# How to visually and individually control external and integrated display brightness

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, brightness

I'm a Ubuntu (and Linux in general) newbie, so...
I have a Ubuntu 18.04 installation with the latest NVidia proprietary driver (version 415) installed, but the brightness slider just affects the internal monitor instead of the external one (I'm using an Apple Cinema Display 27") connected via a mini DisplayPort of my laptop.

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:95e1]
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] [10de:1ba1] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] [1558:95e1]
```